# single quote and $ in string bash

Tags: bash

Im running the below script to run some checks on file paths within a function
Some of the paths contains single quotes and the temporary files contain "$"
If I enclose the variable in single quotes (name variable below) then the string in truncated if there is a ' in the file path.  If I use a double quote around the filepath then it truncates if there is a "$" in the path.
Is there any way out of this circular conundrum?

```
File=/root/fed/~$reader.txt
```

Is echoing as if there is a $ in the file path

```
/root/fed/eager.txt
```

if there is a ' in the file path and I enclose around single quote (to stop the above from happening) then

```
File='/root/fed/reader's'
(this wont echo)
```

Code is :

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c "fnchash 'name'" 

fnchash () {
    echo "$1"
}
```

Comment: I'm confused: are you just trying to write file names like `~$reader.txt` and `reader's`?

Comment: Yes so I'm trying to go through millions of files and some of them contain $ and/or '.   I'm trying to put them into a variable to process.   But my attempts at encapsulating the files in single or double quotes is not helping as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way out of this conundrum is to stop trying to treat data as code. This snippet passes filenames as data (arguments) instead of trying to inject them into a code string, thereby preventing these issues entirely:

```
$ cat myscript 
fnchash () {
    for arg
    do
      printf "Now processing: %s\n" "$arg"
    done
}
export -f fnchash

find . -type f -exec bash -c 'fnchash "$@"' _ {} +

$ ls -1
File with space and '.txt
myscript
some file.txt

$ bash myscript 
Now processing: ./some file.txt
Now processing: ./myscript
Now processing: ./File with space and '.txt
```

This uses the fact that you can call `bash -c 'command' argv0 argv1 argv2..` to run `'command'` with the positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, `$2`.. set to arguments passed to bash and process them as if they were arguments to a script ([man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) under `-c`).

`-exec bash -c 'command' _ {} +` is then used to run `command` with `$0` set to a dummy value `_` and the rest of the parameters set to filenames that `find` finds ([man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) under `-exec`).

The bash command can then process these arguments just like any script would.

The same technique can also be used with `xargs`, here to parallelize the process 5 ways in chunks of 20 files:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 5 -n 20 bash -c 'fnchash "$@"' _
```

Comment: seems like it captures strings with $ and '.   I always thought putting it through xargs was going to be faster hence my approach above.  But running through / on my own machine gave no performance improvement with xargs.  Please could you explain what the " _ {} + " part of the script is doing?

Comment: thanks - Is it possible to use this approach with xargs?

Comment: @AShah Yes, but don't bother with xargs unless you want to parallelize it. The five year old forum posts saying xargs is always faster are from the time before GNU find had xargs functionality built in (with `-exec .. +`)

Answer (score 6):

Single-quoted strings may not contain single quotes.  Not even by escaping them.  Unquoted or double-quoted and unescaped `$` introduces a variable reference that expands to the value of the referenced shell variable, or to nothing if no such variable is defined.

One solution involves double quotes and escape characters.  For example:

```
File=/root/fed/~\$reader.txt
File=/root/fed/reader\'s
File="/root/fed/\$reader's.txt"
```

Note, too, that quotes are not necessarily *string* delimiters -- they are *sub*string delimiters.  Thus, these work, too:

```
File=/root/fed/~'$'reader.txt
File=/root/fed/reader"'"s
```

If you need to perform automatic quoting of data read at runtime, then you should also be aware of `bash`'s built-in `printf` command (which is more featureful than what you may have as a standalone command).  Note in particular that the `%q` field descriptor performs all needed quoting on its arguments to make them re-usable as shell input.

```
printf '%q' $File
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using single quotes and replacing all single quotes with escaped ones,
Or
Using double quotes and replacing all $ with escaped ones.